# After installation lombok eclipse stopped working

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, lombok

I have started to learn Spring with book Spring in action. In chapter 2 author uses Lombok. I wrote annotation @Data, @RequiredArgsConstructor but it doesn't work. Then I tried download lombok from official site and install with terminal. When I installed lombok, my eclipse stopped working. I get a error JVM terminated. Exit code=1. I don't understand why.Please help me. My linux system - fedora workstation 32, ide - eclipse. My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup<br/>
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar <br/>
--launcher.library <br/>
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552<br/>
-product<br/>
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product<br/>
-showsplash<br/>
org.eclipse.epp.package.common<br/>
--launcher.defaultAction<br/>
openFile<br/>
--launcher.defaultAction<br/>
openFile<br/>
--launcher.appendVmargs<br/>
-vmargs<br/>
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8<br/>
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace<br/>
-XX:+UseG1GC<br/>
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication<br/>
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM<br/>
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8<br/>
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true<br/>
-Xms256m<br/>
-Xmx2048m<br/>
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM<br/>
-Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/eclipse/configuration<br/>
--patch-module=java.base=/app/eclipse/flatpak-dev-shim.jar<br/>
-javaagent:/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.eclipse.Java/x86_64/stable/d4c91ac7edee3f6afb68040498d32d5857e12079794fd0be8ec1fae9279450bd/files/eclipse/lombok.jar <br/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the last line of `eclipse.ini` file for:

`-javaagent:/app/eclipse/lombok.jar`

Flatpak runs isolated, so it has his own environment. The .jar will be mounted in `/app/eclipse` folder.

OR

You can install the plugin via "Install New Software..." menu as documented in https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse.